# Why does using combinations give "java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.TraversableOnce$FlattenOps$$anon$1"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Problem:**

I have RDD in form `Array[Array[String]]` and I need combination of strings in the inner array. But when I am applying map function I am getting the following error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.TraversableOnce$FlattenOps$$anon$1
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.collection.TraversableOnce$FlattenOps$$anon$1, value: non-empty iterator)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lscala.collection.Iterator;, size 10)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:324)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Background:**

Initially I have following:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([cyber crimes ;; cyber security ;; review ;; india ;; instances ;; state ;; issue], [civil rights ;; case ;; instances ;; frequency])
```

When I am cleaning this with the following code:

```
words.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String].split("\\;;").map(_.trim))
```

Its result is following:

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(cyber crimes, cyber security, review, india, instances, state, issue), Array(civil society, instances, frequency))
```

Now I need all possible combinations of Strings in Array like:

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array((cyber crimes, cyber security), (review, india), (instances, state), (issue,cyber crimes))....etc)
```

When I am applying `map` on this its giving me above error:

```
val combinations = cleanwords.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String].combinations(2))
```

Can anyone help me to get this desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens probably because trying to collect the rdd where the elements are Iterators (generated by `combinations`). Besides, you need `combinations` directly on the array:

```
cleanwords.map(_.combinations(2).toArray).collect
// res47: Array[Array[Array[String]]] = Array(Array(Array(cyber crimes, cyber security), Array(cyber crimes, review), Array(cyber crimes, india) ..
```

To get back tuples:

```
cleanwords.map(_.combinations(2).map(x => (x(0), x(1))).toArray).collect
// res60: Array[Array[(String, String)]] = Array(Array((cyber crimes,cyber security), (cyber crimes,review), (cyber crimes,india) ..
```